# Determine real indices from flat position

Tags: swift

These are my structs:

```
struct Category{
    var category_name = String()
    var items = [Item]()
}

struct Item{
    var rows = [Row]()
}

struct Row{
    var size: Int
}
```

I have a menu object which is an array of Category. Each Category is an array of Item. Each Item is an array of Row.

```
var menu = [
    Category(category_name: "category1", items: [Item(rows: [Row(size: 1), Row(size: 1)]), Item(), Item()]),
    Category(category_name: "category2", items: [Item(), Item(rows: [Row(size: 1), Row(size: 1), Row(size: 1)]), Item(rows: [Row(size: 1)])])
]
```

I populate the menu, and have a structure like this:

```
-category1 // section 0, row 0
    -item1 // section 0, row 1
        -row1 // section 0, row 2
        -row2 // section 0, row 3
    -item2 // section 0, row 4
    -item3 // section 0, row 5
-category2 // section 1, row 0
    -item1 // section 1, row 1
    -item2 // section 1, row 2
        -row1 // section 1, row 3
        -row2 // section 1, row 4
        -row3 // section 1, row 5
    -item3 // section 1, row 6
        -row1 // section 1, row 7
```

**Given a section and row (flat position), I need to determine:**

1. Row type (`Category`, `Item`, or `Row`)
2. If row type is `Item` or `Row`, the index of the item
3. If row type is `Row`, the index of the row

Here are some example section and row values and the expected results:

```
**indexPath.section = 1**
**indexPath.row = 0**
Row type = category

**indexPath.section = 0**
**indexPath.row = 1**
Row type = item
Item index = 0

**indexPath.section = 0**
**indexPath.row = 3**
cell type = row
Item index = 0
Row index = 1
```

So after determining the results for a specific section and row I would expect to have some logic like this:

```
switch rowtype{
case category:
    print("category")
case item:
    print("item")
    print(itemindex)
case row:
    print("row")
    print(itemindex)
    print(rowindex)
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: provide code which is responsible for populating menu

Comment: I added code to populate the menu

Comment: @Gimmethe411 where do you want to access `rowtype` property? on click of a cell?

Comment: @AgentSmith rowtype property should be created by the answer, but yes I want to access section and row values on click of a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looping through items and rows you should be able to determine the row type. Here is my function for doing this (this was typed on Windows so I haven't compiled or test it but hopefully it will be understandable)

```
enum RowType { 
    case category
    case item(index: Int)
    case row(itemIndex: Int, index: Int)
 }

struct Category{
    var category_name = String()
    var items = [Item]()

    func rowType(_ row: Int) -> RowType {
        if row == 0 { //row 0 means we have a section selected
            return RowType.category
        }
        var itemIndex: Int = 0
        var rowCount: Int = 1
        for x in items {
            itemIndex += 1
            if row == rowCount {
                return RowType.item(index: itemIndex)
            }
            let lastRow = x.rows.count + rowCount
            if row > lastRow {                   
                rowCount += lastRow //not in this item, try next Item
                continue
            }            
            return RowType.row(itemIndex: itemIndex, index: row - itemIndex - 1)
        }
        return RowType.category //Category without items
    }
}
```

and call this using

```
let category = menu[indexPath.section]
let rowInfo = category.rowType(indexPath.row)
```

Comment: It's nice, but am I correct to understand that it doesn't return both the item and row indices?

Comment: @Gimmethe411 Sorry, I missed that requirement. I have an idea how to do it though.

Comment: @Gimmethe411, updated my answer. I have changed the enum to make use of associated values.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to adapt your datasource to the UITableView. I would write a small adaptor `struct` for that:

Your row types

```
enum RowType {
    case category
    case item
    case row
}
```

Your datasource adaptor:

```
struct CategoryTalbleViewDatasource {
    let datasource: [Category]

    var numberOfSections: Int {
        return datasource.count
    }

    func numberOfRows(in section: Int) -> Int {
        let numberOfItems = datasource[section].items.count
        // Total number consists of 1 category + numeber of items + all rows in all items
        return datasource[section].items.flatMap({ $0.rows }).count + numberOfItems + 1
    }

    func type(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> RowType {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            return RowType.category
        case 1:
            return RowType.item
        default:
            return RowType.row
        }
    }
}
```

Initialize your adaptor with your data. e.g.:

```
let row = Row(size: 0)
let item = Item(rows: [row, row, row])
let menu = [
    Category(category_name: "category1", items: [item]),
    Category(category_name: "category2", items: [item, item])
]

let adaptedDatasource = CategoryTalbleViewDatasource(datasource: menu)
```

Later in your table view datasource methods:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
     return adaptedDatasource.numberOfSections
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return adaptedDatasource.numberOfRows(in: section)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let type = adaptedDatasource.type(for: indexPath)

    switch type {
    case .category:
        // return category cell
    case .item:
        // return item cell
    case .row:
        // return item cell
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks good to show which type of cell to return, but I also want to populate the cell with data from the menu. So I think your answer only answers #1 of the 3 requirements.

Comment: You can add associated values to your enum cases e.g. `case category(Category)` and in the datasource `struct` return types with values associated to types.

Comment: You mean to always return the same value for a given RowType? I mean for example that the row.size value can be different, so I need to find such values for the given row.